# Rails: Unpermitted parameter in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

First of all I want simply get an object inside the current object that I'm sending to my *backend*.

I have this simple `JSON` (generated from a form):

```
{
  "name": "Project 1",
  "project_criteria": [
    {
      "name": "Criterium 1",
      "type": "Type 1",
      "benefit": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Criterium 2",
      "type": "Type 2",
      "benefit": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

My `classes`:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_criteria
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_criteria
end

class ProjectCriterium < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end
```

**ProjectsController:**

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name,  project_criteria: [] )
end
```

But I still can't access `project_criteria` parameter as you can see below:

```
Started POST "/projects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-19 16:24:03 -0300
Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"project"=>{"name"=>"Project 1", "project_criteria"=>{"0"=>{"benefit"=>"1", "name"=>"Criterium 1", "type"=>"Type 1"}, "1"=>{"benefit"=>"3", "name"=>"Criterium 2", "type"=>"Type 2"}}}}
Unpermitted parameter: project_criteria # <-----------
```

**Note:**

By the way, I already tried to use **criterium** instead of **criteria**(which **- in my opinion -** is the correct since it should be pluralized) in `has_many` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but it also doesn't work.

Does someone have a solution for this?

Comment: Minor note: the singular of criteria is **criterion**

Comment: Perhaps it's an app about bike races  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's not the inflection of the word "criteria" that's giving you problems (although you can add a custom inflector to get the singular and plural versions you prefer if you really want).

The issue is that you have to explicitly permit the fields of nested objects.

Change your current params:

```
params.require(:project).permit(:name,  project_criteria: [] )
```

To this (for a single nested object):

```
params.require(:project).permit(:name,  project_criteria: [:name, :type, :benefit] )
```

Your case is somewhat compounded by the fact that you're dealing with multiple nested objects, so you'll have to pass a hash instead:

```
params.require(:project).permit(:name,  { project_criteria: [:name, :type, :benefit]} )
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but using both ways that you suggested gives: `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (ProjectCriterium(#39449900) expected, got Array(#17940440)):`

Comment: I guess you're passing JSON as a hash? This may sound dumb, but... if you want an array at the end, pass a hash (my example). If you want a hash at the end, pass an array (which seems to be what you want), so just replace the curlies with square braces and give it a shot.

Comment: Well, I was passing that way that I posted in the initial part of my question, but it's coming as `hash` (`"project_criteria"=>{"0"=>{"benefit"=>"1", "name"=>"Criterium 1", "type"=>"Type 1"}, "1"=>{"benefit"=>"3", "name"=>"Criterium 2", "type"=>"Type 2"}}}}`). By the way, I want an array at the end.. but unfortunately both of your suggestions give me that error.

Comment: Did you try combining our answers? Rename to attributes as well as explicitly listing nested attributes? The error is basically saying that Rails expected an instance of ProjectCriterium, but it got an array instead, so I'm guessing that error is coming after the data is passed. I'd modify the `create` method by swapping `save!` for `save` to see if more detailed exceptions are generated while attempting to save nested objects.

Comment: @developer033 The abve comment is very true. You have too keep the attribute name inside `[]`, with `:id` key. You can't keep that blank.

Comment: @developer033 You also should go and read the link I gave. That will help you to understand how this method works. U need to follow some conventions, that Rails uses to do some behind the scene magics.

Comment: @MarsAtomic, well, I'm still working in another part.. I need to get the parameter first, then I can work on create or another method..  #Arup Rakshit, I tried to put all the *attributes* as you mentioned (combining with your answer, so I have this: `params.require(:project).permit(:name,  project_criteria_attributes: [:name, :type, :benefit] )`, but I get this error: `ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError (attribute is defined by Active Record. Check to make sure that you don't have an attribute or method with the same name.):`

Comment: @ArupRakshit, well I read that link, but still can't make work following all conventions..

Comment: @ArupRakshit, I just forgot to check it as answer. Your answer totally works. The problem was on my side, I had an `attribute` called `attribute` (funny).. I had to change it to make it work again.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue when working on a Rails 6 application.

My application consists of a `User` model that has a one-to-one relationship a `Personal_Info` model

My original code was this:

**User Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord 
  has_one :personal_info, class_name: 'PersonalInfo', dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :personal_info, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**Personal Info Model**

```
class PersonalInfo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**User Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
  .
  .

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,
                                 personal_info_attributes: [:first_name,  
                                 :last_name, :phone, :gender, :dob, 
                                 :address, :city, :state, :country])
  end
end
```

The issue was that I did not add the Personal_Info id to the accepted user params (parameters).

**Here's how I fixed it**:

I simply had to add the Personal_Info `id` to the **UsersController** params this way:

**User Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
  .
  .

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,
                                 personal_info_attributes: [:id, :first_name,  
                                 :last_name, :phone, :gender, :dob, 
                                 :address, :city, :state, :country])
  end
end
```

Another way is to add the `update_only` option to the **Users Model** this way:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord 
  has_one :personal_info, class_name: 'PersonalInfo', dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :personal_info, update_only: true, allow_destroy: true
end
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**