# Rails 5: nested form not saving on Update with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm a bit stuck as with modal window where there are nested form (User Roles below) and which is not working on Update action.

In */controllers/users_controller.rb* I have this code:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @role = Role.where(user_id: @user)
  respond_to do |format|
  if @user.update(user_params)
  format.json { head :no_content }
  format.js
  else
  format.json { render json: @user.errors.full_messages,
                         status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
end

private

  def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :locale, :psw_change,
  roles_attributes: [:id, :general, :dashboard, :reports, :rights] )
  end
```

Then there is partial where forms are generated - */views/users/_form.html.erb*

```
<div class="panel-heading">
  <div class="panel-options">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#roles" data-toggle="tab">Roles</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<%= form_for(@user, remote: true, html: { role: "form" }) do |f| %>
<div class="panel-body">
<form method="get" class="form-horizontal">
<!-- Here we render User profile tab -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="profile">
    <div id="error_explanation" class="bg-danger text-danger"></div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Name"%>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "E-mail"%>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Password"%>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Password confirmation"%>
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- Here we render User roles tab -->
  <div class="tab-pane" id="roles">
    <%= f.fields_for :roles, @role do |role| %>
      <%= render 'common/roles/general', f: role %>
    <% end %>
    <div class='row'></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <%= f.submit  @user.new_record? ? "Create User" : "Update User", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<% end %>
```

On Update action in console I see this:

```
Started PATCH "/lv/users/1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-03-14 18:13:21 +0000
Processing by UsersController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"name"=>"Name 123", "email"=>"some_name@some_mail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "locale"=>"lv", "psw_change"=>"90", "roles_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"general"=>"seller_buyer", "dashboard"=>"deleter", "reports"=>"deleter", "rights"=>"deleter", "id"=>"1"}}}, "commit"=>"Update User", "locale"=>"lv", "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Role Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
  Role Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."user_id" = $1 AND "roles"."id" = 1  [["user_id", 1]]
  User Exists (1.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER($1) AND ("users"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["email", "some_name@some_mail.com"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.7ms)  COMMIT
  Rendering users/update.js.erb
  Rendered users/_user.html.erb (2.6ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered layouts/_userprofile.html.erb (0.7ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered users/update.js.erb (173.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1821ms (Views: 376.4ms | ActiveRecord: 599.1ms)
```

Strange thing is **it does not save User Role updated values, however it would save User Profile updated values if there is such update needed**. Obviously I'm missing here something, but I don't see what exactly. I would be happy for any help. Thank you!

**The solution**

If anyone needs, here is what was wrong in my form. Basically the view part of *_form.html.erb* was not correct, so values were not updating. It has to be like this:

```
<!-- Here we render User roles tab -->
  <div class="tab-pane" id="roles">
    <%= f.fields_for :roles, @role do |role| %>
      <%= render 'common/roles/general', f: role %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <%= f.submit  @user.new_record? ? "Create User" : "Update User", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it because you commented out `@role.update`?

Comment: @ChrisPeters Sorry, It's not about that - I deleted that line + added user_params

Comment: Is the roles' relation to users a has_one or a has_many?

Comment: @Glyoko It's `has_many :roles` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes[:name].blank? }` in User model

Comment: Also, it helps others if you indent your code properly. Take a minute to save a minute for everyone who is trying to help you.

Comment: @ChrisPeters True, I should be more accurate. I forgot I got that line & forgot I should have added `user_params` as that really matters in my case. It seems that there could be something wrong how I'm passing params. So far I tried to do it like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39046713)