# Unpermitted Parameter for Nested Resource in JSON Payload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I am having difficulty sending a JSON payload to an endpoint that contains a nested resource that I would like created with associations in-tact and persisted... no matter what I do I am presented in the console with `Unpermitted parameter: :ingredients`.

**models/meal.rb**

```
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end
```

**models/ingredient.rb**

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :meal
end
```

**controller/meals_controller.rb**

```
class MealsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @meal = Meal.new(meal_params)
    puts meal_params.inspect
    # just want to see the parameters in the log
    # ...
  end

  private
    def meal_params
      params.require(:meal).permit(
        :name,
        ingredients_attributes: [:id, :text]
      )
    end
  end
```

**db/migrate/xxx_create_inredients.rb**

```
class CreateIngredients < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :ingredients do |t|
      t.belongs_to :meal, index: true
      t.string :text
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**request JSON payload**

```
{
  "meal": {
    "name": "My Favorite Meal",
    "ingredients": [
      { "text": "First ingredient" },
      { "text": "Second ingredient" }
    ]
  }
}
```

---

I tried another approach [from a SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39046713) encountering a similar problem that seemed to recognize the ingredients parameter, but ultimately threw a 500:
`params.require(:meal).permit(:name, { ingredients:  [:id, :text] })`

When doing that I receive the following:
`ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Ingredient(#70235637684840) expected, got {"text"=>"First Ingredient"} which is an instance of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70235636442880))`

---

Any help in pointing out my flaw is much appreciated. And yes, I want the nested ingredients resource to be part of the payload going to this endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem that you have here is that you have in your meal params ingredients_attributes

```
def meal_params
  params.require(:meal).permit(
    :name,
    ingredients_attributes: [:id, :text]
  )
end
```

so in your payload you need to have it with that key too

```
{
  "meal": {
    "name": "My Favorite Meal",
    "ingredients_attributes": [
      { "text": "First ingredient" },
      { "text": "Second ingredient" }
    ]
  }
}
```

they need to match.

Comment: Oh wow, now that you spell it out, that makes perfect sense. Thank you.