# Unpermitted parameter: :images in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and have started building my first api; I'm attempting to send an array of strings down as one of the parameters in my api request, like this:

```
{
  "name": "doot doot",
  "plans": "",
  "sketches": "",
  "images": ["foo.png", "bar.png"]
}
```

Originally, `images` was a string but I ran a migration to alter it to allow for an array of strings instead, like this:

```
 change_column :projects, :images, "varchar[] USING (string_to_array(images, ','))"
```

In the controller I've defined the `create` function as:

```
def create
  project = Project.create(project_params)
  render json: project
end

def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, :plans, :sketches, :images)
end
```

but I still get the following error:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :images. Context: { controller: ProjectsController, action: create, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00007fb6f4e50e90>, params: {"name"=>"Simple Box", "plans"=>"", "sketches"=>"", "images"=>["foo.png", "bar.png"], "controller"=>"projects", "action"=>"create", "project"=>{"name"=>"Simple Box", "plans"=>"", "sketches"=>"", "images"=>["foo.png", "bar.png"]}} }
```

I consulted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046532/rails-unpermitted-parameter-in-rails-5) but the solutions didn't work; any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify that `images` is an array.

```
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, :plans, :sketches, images: [])
```

See [Permitted Scalar Values](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#permitted-scalar-values) in the Rails Guides.