# Convert array of string to an array of images

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a follow on from my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71402693/unpermitted-parameter-images-in-rails). What I want to do now is convert the column type for `projects` to hold an array of images.

I've built the ability for a user to upload an image to Rails but want them to be able to upload an array of images for a project; I'm not quite sure as to how to go about it.

I've thought about creating a migration that converts the column type of `images` from an array of strings to an array of images:

```
def up
  change_column :projects, :images, ?
end

def down
  change_column :projects, :images, ?
end
```

but I don't know how to use the image as a type.

An example of what returns from a GET for the images looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "doot.png",
    "featured_image": {
        "url": "http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/3joi32jo23nfkjsnjksefsdnansdf--daf5e3e6b3772510ada4077c2172b117e81f8f85/doot.png"
    }
  }
]
```

Pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: This whole idea is bonkers. Storing "an array of images" in a single column isn't something you actually do in a SQL database. While databases have binary column types I have never heard of a database that stores arrays of binary blobs in a single column. The sane way to approach the problem is to create a join table and store one image (binary or a link to the image) per row.

Comment: Well I'm not very familiar with databases and BE tech in general so forgive my ignorance on what the approach should be as I was asking to be pointed in the right direction - would the question have been better if I had of asked how to do it without showing any work?

Comment: Well. You don't need any of this - ActiveStorage takes care of the actual storage for you. You don't need to add any columns to your tables since ActiveStorage stores attachments (the metadata about the files) on a seperate table and links back to your model with a polymorphic assocation. You need to start by [reading the manual](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html).